# Active Directory How to view hidden attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

Premise, it is first time I work with Active Directory (my project is a web app in Asp.Net MVC).

For a User in Active Directory I need to read an attribute `givenName` in my C#.

My questions:

1. Using Active Directory Browser on Windows Server I cannot see `givenName` attribute for a user. Can this attribute be hidden from the view in Active Directory?
2. Could you provide me a sample of code which allow me to take the `givenName` attribute knowing the UserName for the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here.... 
   string givenName = user.GivenName;    
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I was able to answer my first question reading this article http://www.stuartclowes.com/2011/10/displaying-hidden-attributes-in-active.html